# How to filter elements from a list based in another list and get percentages

Tags: python, arrays, list, for-loop, filter

I want to get elements from a list such as

```
appeared_elements = ['blue-sky','road','white-horse','green-field','tree','dusthaze-sky','brown-horse','yellow-field','black-bison','green-field','dusthaze-sky','dusthaze-sky','blue-sky','snowy-field']
```

and return the frequency of how many times those elements appear in another list

```
objects = ['black-bison', 'elephant', 'white-horse', 'brown-horse', 'scarlet-ibis', 'black-ibis', 'white-ibis', 'blue-sky', 'overcast-sky', 'cloudy-sky', 'dusthaze-sky', 'rocky-mountain', 'snowy-mountain', 'birdseye-building', 'perspective-building', 'front-building', 'red-flower', 'purple-flower', 'pink-flower', 'sand', 'tree', 'green-field', 'snowy-field', 'yellow-field', 'road', 'tower', 'blue-ocean', 'green-cliff', 'black-cliff', 'waterfall']
```

I came up with a solution...

```
def printPercentages(appeared_elements, objects):
  for n in objects:
    soma = len([m for m if n in appeared_elements])/len(appeared_elements)
    print(soma)
```

But I am failing somewhere I don't know where yet

Comment: Looks like a typo in your list comprehension -- should be `[m for m in objects if m in appeared_elements]`, or something like that?

Comment: Could you give an example of what you expect the output to be?  I'm not sure what "frequency of how many times those elements appear in another list" means -- is it the percentage of elements (unique or not?) in `appeared_elements` that appear in `objects`, or the reverse of that, or the frequency with which each element repeats within `objects`, or...?

Comment: @Samwise... Yes, that is it the percentage of elements (unique or not?) in appeared_elements that appear in objects

Comment: you didn't answer the "unique or not?" part...

Comment: Not unique, @Samwise

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you might find `collections.Counter` to be a useful module here. It yields a dictionary with every unique item in an array as a key and the number of times that item occurs in the array as the value. For example, if you had the array `['a', 'b', 'c', 'b']`, then  `Counter(['a', 'b', 'c', 'b']) => {'a': 1, 'b': 2, 'c': 1}`

So for your purposes, you'd create a counter for your `objects` array and then use that to determine how often one of your `appeared_elements` shows up in the `objects` array.

```
from collections import Counter

def printPercentages(objects, appeared_elements):
    counter = Counter(objects)
    soma = {}
    for e in appeared_elements:
        soma[e] = (counter.get(e) or 0)/len(objects) * 100 # this will give you the freq of each element saved to a dictionary so you can see them all.
    print(soma)
```

For the sample data you gave, your output would be:

```
{
    "black-bison": 7.142857142857142,
    "elephant": 0.0,
    "white-horse": 7.142857142857142,
    "brown-horse": 7.142857142857142,
    "scarlet-ibis": 0.0,
    "black-ibis": 0.0,
    "white-ibis": 0.0,
    "blue-sky": 14.285714285714285,
    "overcast-sky": 0.0,
    "cloudy-sky": 0.0,
    "dusthaze-sky": 21.428571428571427,
    "rocky-mountain": 0.0,
    "snowy-mountain": 0.0,
    "birdseye-building": 0.0,
    "perspective-building": 0.0,
    "front-building": 0.0,
    "red-flower": 0.0,
    "purple-flower": 0.0,
    "pink-flower": 0.0,
    "sand": 0.0,
    "tree": 7.142857142857142,
    "green-field": 14.285714285714285,
    "snowy-field": 7.142857142857142,
    "yellow-field": 7.142857142857142,
    "road": 7.142857142857142,
    "tower": 0.0,
    "blue-ocean": 0.0,
    "green-cliff": 0.0,
    "black-cliff": 0.0,
    "waterfall": 0.0
}
```

Comment: Ah, the `objects` and `appeared_elements` were backwards from my understanding - I will edit my answer. Also, I added a `* 100` to give you the percentage